# parent::método não retorna conexão

Tags: php

Tenho uma classe **Conn** que faz uma conexão a um SQL Server:

```
class Conn
{
    protected $con;
    protected $a = 'aaa';

    function __construct()
    {
        $this -> conecta();
    }

    private function conecta(){
        $serverName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XXX", "UID"=>"YYY", "PWD"=>"ZZZ", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");

        try {
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Erro na conexão com o BD.<br/>";
            die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

        if (!$conn){
            echo "Erro na conexão com o BD.<br/>";
            die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        } else {
            $this -> con = $conn;
            var_dump($this -> con);
        }
    }

    protected function getCon(){
        return $this -> con;
    }

}
```

E uma classe **BD** que **estende** a classe **Conn**:

```
class BD extends Conn
{
    private $cnx;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this -> cnx = parent::getCon();
        var_dump($this -> cnx);
    }
}
```

---

Quando crio um objeto de **BD**:

Se no método `getCon()` eu setar `return $this -> a;`, me retorna: `string(3) "aaa"`

Se no método `getCon()` eu setar `return $this -> con;`, me retorna: `NULL` onde deveria retornar `resource(3) of type (SQL Server Connection)`

---

Gostaria de saber o que poderia estar causando isso ou se estou usando incorretamente.

Comment: Não faltou chamar o construtor da classe mãe em `BD`? E por quê chamar `parent::getCon()` ao invés de `$this->getCon()`?

Comment: Não entendi o "chamar o construtor da classe mãe em BD"... Se eu chamar `$this->getCon()` em `BD` eu estaria chamando um método de `BD`, e não de `Conn`, não é?

Comment: Não, se `BD` **herda** de `Conn`, então ela possuirá o método. Chamará de `BD` somente se você sobrescrevê-lo.

Comment: Ah verdade... não tem `getCon()` na `BD`. Mas porque ele retorna o string e não a conexão?

Comment: Fiz usando `$this -> getCon()` mas continua `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O objeto `$con` em `Conn` só é inicializado quando é chamado o método `Conn::conecta`, que por sua vez é chamado no construtor de `Conn`, porém o construtor de `Conn` nunca é chamado, pois o método foi sobrescrito na classe filha `BD`.

Se você precisa sobrescrever o construtor, você precisará chamar o construtor da classe mãe explicitamente:

```
class BD
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Assim, o construtor da classe mãe será executado, chamando o método `conecta` e inicializando o objeto `$con`. Desta forma, você poderá fazer:

```
class BD
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->cnx = $this->getCon();
    }
}
```

Perceba que foi invocado como `$this->getCon()`, visto que, como o método `Conn::getCon` é *protected*, ele será herdado em `BD` como *private*, estando ainda acessível dentro da classe.

Comment: Sempre preciso chamar o construct da classe mãe? Porque eu renomeei para `function Conn()`e `function BD()`, e mesmo assim não funcionou...

Comment: @RBZ se você sobrescrever o construtor na classe filha, sim.

Comment: Então, mas não sobrescrevi. Renomeei o construtor de `Conn` para `function Conn()`, assim ele está diferente de `function __construct()` em `BD`...

Comment: Então, é um método e você precisará invocá-lo explicitamente. Um método com o mesmo nome da classe não é um construtor - era somente no PHP 4, mas depois do 5 não mais. O único construtor é `__construct`.